Create drop down from list items in SharePoint Online webpart
happy Thursday!
My scenario is I have a list that contains items referencing different aspx pages.  I have a webpart that queries the endpoint and retrieves all of the list items into a drop-down menu.  When you select each item, it displays the text (description column) underneath it, with a link to the aspx page and Title column:
Link to Webpart screen shot (https://i.sstatic.net/Jj4MS.png)
I do not have the source code for this spfx and am having to solve for this issue, it was a tenant-to-tenant migration.  Has anyone out there created something like this already?  Much appreciated.
I have gotten somewhat close with this:
https://www.spguides.com/retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-using-sharepoint-framework/
But that just displays the list items on the page, in a table format.

Hey Ryan, what exactly is the problem you are having?  Not sure that image of the screen shot helps me much.

Thank you, Steve, yea it's not much help looking back at it lol.  Basically, the drop-down menu that's blacked out is an item from /site pages.  When it's selected from the drop down, it displays the description column underneath it (the text from whatever is populated in the description column).
I am not a dev, I am pretty strong in graph/PowerShell etc., was hoping someone had a working example I think I could get this working with an example to work from, if that makes sense.  Thank you.
I don't have source code either.  Just what I could export from the source tenant.

Also:  the reason I have to recreate this is because whomever created the solution hardcoded the tenant in the solution.  That may have been necessary, I am not sure but EncodeAbsUrl is hard path'd to the old tenant when I look at hte .js file created by exported solution.
